# send $_FILES to other function

Tags: php

how send $_FILES to other function?

```
<?php
function save(how get $_FILES["img"] ??)
{
    //$img = $_FILES["img"]; How get  $_FILES["img"] ??
    $user_file = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $file_temp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $new = "new/";

    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $new .$user_file.'');
    echo "<br><b>OK<b>";
}

if(isset($_POST['SEND'])){
    save($_FILES["img"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to move the file from one directory to another or how to pass the value "$_FILES['img']" into a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual variable is `$_FILES`; `$_FILES['img']` is a value stored within that array. You can't pass that value to a function and store it in something named `$_FILES['img']`, but you wouldn't really want to. Name it something like `$img`, and use that:

```
function save($img)
{
    $user_file = $img['name'];
    $file_temp = $img['tmp_name'];
    $new = "new/";

    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $new .$user_file.'');
    echo "<br><b>OK<b>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Files is a (super) global.  You can reference it from within a function just fine.

If you want to factor out some functionality, and invoke a function to act on just some part of the $_FILES superglobal array, you can do something like this:

```
function save($fileKey){
   $file = $_FILES[$fileKey];
   move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],...);
}
save('img');
save('img2');
```

or

```
function save($arrayFile){
   move_uploaded_file($arrayFile['tmp_name'],...);
}
save($_FILES['img');
save($_FILES['img2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

you can see all kinds of good information that is stored in the $_FILES array, including the uploaded file name and the temp location.

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES - is a usual array which structure you can view by `var_dump($_FILES);` You can work with it as with usual array.